# KDB+/Q: how to understand the definitions in the language reference?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to understand the definition of an `atomic` function quoted  [here:](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/atomic/) `.[f;x]~.[f';x]`

Now I believe the `.` is function application as documented [here](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#68-general-application), but what is `f'` in the above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is saying that the two are equivalent and that using `each` is not required in an atomic function i.e. .[f;x] is essentially .[f';x]

You can see this in the example given here where `+` is f and (2;(3 4;5)) x https://code.kx.com/q/basics/atomic/

```
q).[+;(2;(3 4;5))]
5 6
7
q).[+';(2;(3 4;5))]   / the iterator is unnecessary
5 6
7
```

where the function `+` is applied to each item in the nested list using the atomic function